# When approving a suggested edit, the pending edits count on the top passes from 1 to −1

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should it be possible to have a negative number of suggested edits in the queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133602/should-it-be-possible-to-have-a-negative-number-of-suggested-edits-in-the-queue)

I have approved a suggested edit on EL&U, and noticed that the count of the pending edits shown on the top of the page passed from 1 to −1.

[image: screenshot]

As you see, the count shown on the tab is correct.

The software revision used on EL&U is 2012.6.1.2743.

Comment: also noticed on Biology a couple of days ago - still goes away on refresh :L

Comment: I started seeing this a lot yesterday so i think it might actually be new