# Review queue size goes negative

Tags: bug, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should it be possible to have a negative number of suggested edits in the queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133602/should-it-be-possible-to-have-a-negative-number-of-suggested-edits-in-the-queue)

In the past I have noticed that when there are items in the review queue, and you approve them, the queue size (displayed in the page header) didn't get modified, until you refreshed. I see now that that has changed.

Now, it shrinks too far.

In the last two occasions (on Skeptics.SE), the queue size has been 1, I have approved the edit, and the queue size has dropped to "-1".

[image]

On refresh, it (correctly) disappeared (i.e. count = 0)

The first time, I wondered if two of us had edited at the same time, causing a miscount, but the second time it happened that seemed unlikely.

*I was overdue to post another entry into the 'Lowest Priority Bug of the Week' competition. Status-Completed!*