# Negative/0/blank suggested edits counter

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, toolbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should it be possible to have a negative number of suggested edits in the queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133602/should-it-be-possible-to-have-a-negative-number-of-suggested-edits-in-the-queue)

The suggested edits counter seems to have intermittent display issues when hovering around the 0 mark.

Similarly to [Should it be possible to have a negative number of suggested edits in the queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133602/140505), I have just seen this on Programmers:

[image: negative pending edits]

This occurred just after I approved the only pending edit. The homepage in the mean time has a blank pending edits notification (just the brown area without *any* text).

It is not the first time this has happened, but it will not happen *every* time. On occasion I have seen the pending edits area go to 0, -1 and be blank, just after approving/rejecting the last remaining suggested edit.

I have not been able to reliably reproduce the behaviour.

Update:

And now, with a 0:

[image: 0 pending edits]

Comment: Well I like -1 a lot better than 196. :-)